# How do I plot a Histogram of Oriented Gradients?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scikit-image

How do I plot a HOG using matplotlib? I cannot find out how people do plot it like the following example:

https://gurus.pyimagesearch.com/lesson-sample-histogram-of-oriented-gradients-and-car-logo-recognition/#tour_modal

I've looked around matplotlib website but no luck at all trying to find the right example. ¿Does anyone know how to plot it or where I can learn it?

I've been trying this for now with no luck. https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/statistics/histogram_histtypes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-statistics-histogram-histtypes-py

I just need to identify the pixel distribution within the 9 bins of HOG and the degrees of the strokes.

Comment: Here's an example from the scikit-image gallery: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_hog.html

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Thanks for your reply but that's how to compute HOG. I've already done that. Like I said, I need to plot what I've computed so far.

Comment: Here's how we visualize the result: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/feature/_hog.py#L236

Answer (score 0):

The Histogram allow to us to obtain the relative frequency of each level of gray of the image, in opencv we can get the histogram of this way:

## With bins:

```
image = cv2.imread('example.jpg')
imagex = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

plt.hist(imagex.ravel(), bins=8, range=(0,255))
plt.show()
```

You will get one histogram based on bins,
but if you wan get all the histogram of your image try it:

```
image = cv2.imread('myimage.jpeg')
imagex = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.hist(imagex.ravel(),256,[0,256]);
plt.show()
```

Best Regards!